# Child to child components communicate using angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Any one explain in  Angular 4 [Parent Component and both child component] its possible to pass data from child to child component

An example on each would be helpful in understanding both the cases. In what scenario can we use each case?

## If parent to child component passing data i used @Input Decorator as same child to parent passing data  i used @Output Decorator and Event Emitter.

Comment: Have u tried reading this on google. There are plenty ref: https://ciphertrick.com/2017/07/24/parent-child-component-communication-angular/

Comment: You should pass data from child to parent and pass it again from parent to another child.

Comment: when the relations between two component is not parent-child I think is better using a service. You can use a service like it's showed in  https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service. Or using getter/setters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112868/call-function-from-one-component-to-another-to-update-the-button?noredirect=1&lq=1