# How to use DetailComponent Code in HeaderComponent in Angular

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 14 and I have 2 Components. `HeaderComponent` and `DetailComponent`. Both of the Components have tightly integrated code between their `Html` and `ts` files. Now I want to just move the `Button` placed in `DetailComponent` to `HeaderComponent` with some attached attributes like `ngIf`, `disabled` etc.

What is the best way of moving the `Button` from `DetailComponent` to `HeaderComponent` with the same functionality as before?

Is it possible by adding a new `SharedService` between the two `Components`?

Comment: It would be difficult to move the tightly integrated code from `DetailComponent` to `HeaderComponent`. Is there any shortcut for this like firing an event?

Comment: ther're a lot of example to comunicate two components not relationship parent-child. e.g. in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48112868/call-function-from-one-component-to-another-to-update-the-button/48127886#48127886) in one component you "emit" a value (your header) to an observable and the other (your DetailComponent) "listen" this observable. In subscribe you can call to the same function you use to the button instead of simply change the value of a variable.Another link: the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service)

Comment: Use a service is **the only** if not shared the same `<router-outlet>` (e.g. your app has a header and a <router-outlet>, and in this router-outlet is where you load your "detailComponent"). If not, you can use a template reference variable in your DetailComponent, and pass as `@Input` to your "headerComponent". In this way you can access to all the public variables and methods of your component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, employing a shared service is a viable solution to facilitate communication between the HeaderComponent and DetailComponent.

Alternatively, you can use a parent-child relationship between components to share data. If HeaderComponent is a child of DetailComponent, it can communicate through input properties and output events. However, this might not be the best approach in terms of component hierarchy and naming conventions.

Comment: There are lot of changes in `ngOnChanges()` event of `DetailComponent`. Should we need to move all that code to `HeaderComponent` or `SharedService`?