# Is it possible to run the functions in another component.ts?

Tags: angular

I got this on a button on x.component.html

`(click)='xxManageSearchFormClick()'`

but the problem is xxManageSearchFormClick is located in y.component.ts

and is there a way in angular x.component.html to be able to run the y.component.ts's functions?

This is kind of like running the function of a parent window (in traditional html/window/js interaction )

Comment: Here are the various ways to interact between components: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Your question is really unclear. You should know, that how components are related (parent-child, sibilings or routed) does impact in how we as developers can make them interact. Please use concrete examples in your question and more meaningful names.

Comment: The question is clear enough. Read it again. But, Nour has already nailed it.

Comment: JB Nizet, the link you provided is very useful: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction  Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @output() to fire an event from the child component to the parent component once the button has clicked.

In your child component template (HTML):

```
<button type="button" (click)="onClickChlidComponent()">Click me</button>
```

The child component typescript file:

```
import {Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector:'x-component',
})
export class XComponent{
    @Output() buttonXClicked = new EventEmitter();

    onClickChlidComponent(){
      this.buttonXClicked.emit(null);//You can pass whatever you want throw the output
    }
}
```

Your parent component template is:

```
<x-component (buttonXClicked)="onChildXButtonClicked($event)"></x-component>
```

Your parent component typescript:

```
onChildXButtonClicked(outputData:any){
    alert('button on the x component has clicked');
}
```

Comment: So it is possible. Could you tell me what steps are involved?

Comment: Yeah it's possible, please follow the official documentation  https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction and i will update my answer to include an example.

Comment: @AverageJoe, your question is a common question, If your component are not parent-child, you can use a service, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069554/how-to-execute-a-function-from-another-component-that-is-not-a-sibling-of-the-fi